# Geometry Nodes - rotate point along curve tangent

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

How can I rotate each point so that each follows the tangent of the curve using geometry nodes?

Right now, every point’s rotation is the same.

[image]

Comment: looks like a Blender bug for me....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Blender 3.0 and 3.1 you can use curve to point node to rotate instances along curve. Also you should try to capture attribute from curve to make additional changes in instances along curve.

[image]

I give a bit more complex answer here: [Geonodes: Apply point index to group node input](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248400/geonodes-apply-point-index-to-group-node-input/)
I hope it is ok that i copypaste a part of my own answer.