# Geonodes: Apply point index to group node input

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've set a simple "Leaf" geonode to distort a leaf based on two parameters:

[image: Leaf Distortion GeoNode]

Then, I've set a second "Leaves" geonode, to instance multiple leaves along a curve:

[image: Curve Instancer Geonode]

Now I'm trying to apply a different value to each "leaf" created by the "leaves" node.

However, when I plug an "Index Node" to the Group Node, it generates a separate Index for each vertex of the leaf mesh, as expected inside the "Leaf" node, not on the "Leaves", where the Index Node should reflect the Curve points.
What am I missing here?

[image: Index Problem]

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245858/35559) may help with a hack. If you're prepared to use Blender 3.1a, there's an 'Instance' domain to stash per-instance attributes, which can be captured, and  are successfully inherited on the points of realised geometry.

Comment: I'm a bit confused to what you're trying to accomplish. The instances don't exist yet before being instanced by the *Instance on Points*. You're applying the index to the geometry acting as the blueprint for them, therefore whatever you do to it will be passed on to all instances equally. There are ways to generate different leaves from GN geometry: In 3.1 you can "Pick Instance" from a randomized set of different leaves created beforehand; or you can modify them after instanced with greater control... and effort. What would you like to do?

Comment: @Rhaenys This is my first time using geonodes, so I might be trying to do something nonsensical. However, my ideia is to generate gradually different leaves for each point. I get how I could do 2 or 3 models and instantiate them randomly, but what I need is to apply a procedural distortion to each leaf, based on it's position at the curve. Imagine you have a set of straight lines, which can be bent through a parameter, distributed along a curve. I need the first one to be bent 5°, the second 10°, and so on.

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.**
You can use curve to point node to rotate instances along curve. Also you should try to capture attribute from curve to make additional changes in instances along curve.

[image]

**2.**
If you need to modify objects along curve, you should apply set position node after instance on points node. In this case don't forget to put realize instances node between them. In the example below objects catch the shape of float curve node, and at the same time changes along guide curve.
[image: Objects catch the shape of float curve node]

Comment: Beautiful node setup :)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you :)